# Why doesn't the Regex match?

Tags: regex

```
@^/yolo/[a-z]$@
```

and I am trying to match /yolo/test

but it doesn't match... What in the regular expression can be wrong? It seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: The `[a-z]` construct is a "character class" and only represents 1 possible character.  Maybe try `[a-z]+` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written, this will match `/yolo/` followed by any single letter. I suspect you want to match one or more letters, as in:

```
@^/yolo/[a-z]+$@
```

Comment: He won't need to escape the `/` if he's surrounding it in `@`. He'll just need to escape any additional `@`.

Comment: @OGHaza that's true for PHP, but he didn't specify a backing language.

Comment: I think you'd struggle to find a language that allows regex to be wrapped in `@` whilst still requiring escaping of forward-slashes

Answer (score 2):

```
^/yolo/[a-z]$
```

`^` means match start of line

`/yolo/` matches literally the string /yolo/

`[a-z]` matches one character, a to z

`$` matches the end of line

So you are looking for /yolo/ followed by a single character

Which does not match /yolo/test